# Update entrie X in table Y by entrie Z in table A when entrie X exist in table A

Tags: mysql

I have a table Y with a varchar field that contains a description with variable lenght (X). I want to update the entrie X in table Y when entrie X  exists in another table (A) with the entrie in the other table (Z)

For example if the table A contained:

```
|col1 |
+-----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE|
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE |
```

And table B contained:

```
|col 1||col 2|
+------+
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||20161217_LC_YoBirthdayYES_A_DE  |
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||20160227_NL_Luxus_1_FR |
```

I want a query that will change col 1 in table A as:

```
|col1|
+------+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayYES_A_DE |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE|
|20160227_NL_Luxus_1_FR |
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve this problem... :/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You coud use an update  with inner join

```
update tableA  
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.col1  = tableB.col1
set tableA.col1 = table2.col2
```

Comment: I got no possibility to check it right now: I will give Feedback tomorrow. However many thanks already now!

Comment: looking at you data sample the answer is  still correct ... anyway change quetion  after  a (correct i think ) answer is not fair  ..

Comment: that´s true: I just thought it might be misleading in the "old" description that I only want to change the entries in table A...

Comment: then main concept for you question is that you can easly use a join for get the row on which you need  to work .. then using the normal join properties  you can define the rows set you need ..